# An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to sign up in a portal but I am getting the following error; "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: There isn't much that we can tell you that isn't already said in the error message.  You have tried to pass `null` as the `password` value when attempting to insert a new row into the `profile` table.  We are going toneed to see the code that you've written which leads to this fault.

Comment: Thank you I managed to solve this problem, the issue was brought about by the PHP version that was in use I had to change PHP version 7.4 to 7.0 for it to work.

Comment: Then at this point, you have two options.  You can post an educational answer to your own question OR you can simply delete this question/page yourself.  The only thing you shouldn't do is abandon this page with a comment that says that you resolved your question.

Comment: For educational purpose the problem is brought about by the template shaper helix 3 version 2.2 which does not support PHP 7.1 and above causing it throw errors.

Comment: All diagnostic details should be added to the question as an edit.  Ideally, we never want screenshots of textual details. 
If you are not going to delete this page, please post your resolving insights as a single answer on this page, then delete your comments (and I'll delete my comments).